# Getting the path template from my controller in a HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jersey

Currently I am migrating from Jersey to Spring MVC and need provide the same behaviour and functionality.

In the old situation we had a Jersey ContainerRequestFilter that registers Prometheus metrics. The metric contains the path template of the resource method.
For example:
My resource method:

```
@GET
@Path("/some/path/{id}")
public void myEndpointMethod() {
...
}
```

So within the ContainerRequestFilter we retrieved the path template `"/some/path/{id}"` by using `containerRequest.getUriInfo().getMatchedTemplates();`

In the new situation I created a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` but I can't find a way to retrieve the same path template as defined in my rest controller.

My question is: How can I retrieve the path template within a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`?

To be clear, I don't want to get the requestUri(`"/some/path/aa-bb-234"`) but the matched endpoint pattern(`"/some/path/{id}"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        String path = (String)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
        System.out.println(path);
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
```